# Pandas how to duplicate and add new column with values based off two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a dataframe called contest

There are two columns that I am interested in

TST = Total Shots Taken
SM = Shots made

I want to duplicate this data frame called contest and create a new column dividing SM/TST

I am using pandas and numpy. Steps for making a new duplicate of the dataframe. Adding the new column to the duplicated data frame with this calculation to be called shotperc = shot percentage would be highly helpful. I just started using Jupyter Notebooks this week.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to achieve what you want.

1. copy the original dataframe, store into a new variable, assign the new column to this new variable.

```
new_contest = contest.copy()
new_contest["shot_percent"] = new_contest["shots_made"] / new_contest["shots_taken"]

print(new_contest)
   shots_taken  shots_made  shot_percent
0           90          45          0.50
1          100          50          0.50
2          200         150          0.75
3           80          60          0.75
4           50          10          0.20
```

2. Use the `assign` method, which performs a `copy` implicitly to ensure you original dataframe remains unchanged.

```
new_contest = contest.assign(shot_percent=lambda df: df["shots_made"] / df["shots_taken"])

print(new_contest)
   shots_taken  shots_made  shot_percent
0           90          45          0.50
1          100          50          0.50
2          200         150          0.75
3           80          60          0.75
4           50          10          0.20
```

3. Probably the most uncommon option, but use the `eval` DataFrame method which also copies the original dataframe implicitly to ensure your original data doesn't change. This is also the most readable result imo.

```
new_contest = contest.eval("shot_percent = shots_made / shots_taken")

print(new_contest)
   shots_taken  shots_made  shot_percent
0           90          45          0.50
1          100          50          0.50
2          200         150          0.75
3           80          60          0.75
4           50          10          0.20
```

None of the above methods change your original dataframe, hope this helps!